# How to convert module.exports to json to use in gulp tasks?

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

I'm trying to pass some variables from my JS config file to SASS, by using this gulp plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-data-to-sass, which accepts a JSON file as input.

My config file is the following

```js
// config.js

module.exports = {
    use: {
        gallery: true,
        animations: true,
    },
}
```

how can I convert this to a valid JSON file, preferably with gulp itself, in order to be able to pass it to the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as JSON:

`config.json`:

```
{
    "use": {
        "gallery": true,
        "animations": true,
    }
}
```

That is how the example for the npm package does it. If you need to consume this from JS code elsewhere, you can require JSON.

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

Not sure how you add this to a gulp pipeline, but you can write a helper in your build pipeline that does this:

```
const config = require('./config')
const fs = require('fs')

fs.writeFileSync('./config.json', JSON.stringify(config), 'utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep the config file in js format.

Comment: Added another approach then.

Comment: Thank you, this works but I need to find  how to integrate to the gulp pipe, I'll try to experiment, maybe with vinyl